# How to delete a perforce client with pending changelist

Tags: perforce

I have a workspace in **perforce** in which I made some files mark for delete. Now I want to delete that workspace forcefully.

But I don't have admin rights. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 57):

Run `p4 opened` to see all your opened files and run `p4 revert` to revert them.

Then run `p4 changes -c your-client-name -s pending` to see all your pending changelists. Since in the first step you reverted all your open files, these changelists will all be empty. Run `p4 change -d change-number` to delete each empty pending changelist.

Then you can run `p4 client -d` to delete your client.

Comment: For reverting and deleting a pending changelist, I prefer this sequence:  `p4 changes -u joe` to list my pending changelists; `p4 revert -c 12345 //...` to revert all files in my pending changelist 12345 (for example); `p4 change -d 12345` to delete the now-empty changelist.  HTH.

Comment: @Jeffro your solution, `p4 revert -c CLN //...`  saves my time from revert opened files one by one.

Comment: Also see [KB: Deleting a changelist with shelved files](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3452/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle) in case you have a changelist with shelved files.

Answer (score 49):

Why it's only 11 clicks in P4V, through an arbitrary sequence of menu items.

1. Right click on the changelist
2. Delete shelved files
3. 'Yes'
4. Right click on the changelist
5. Remove all jobs
6. Right click on the changelist
7. Revert files
8. 'Revert'
9. Right click on the changelist
10. Delete pending changelist
11. 'Yes'

Let's send Perforce to usability school.

Comment: You are not always allowed to delete job - *'fix.delete' validation failed: Cannot modify job fixes for jobs that have already been resolved*

Answer (score 21):

Here's a scriptable procedure for deleting a Perforce client. Use with care: this deletes all your work in progress on the client!

1. Revert all changed files on this client.

   ```bash
   p4 -c $CLIENT revert -k //...
   ```

   Note the use of the `-k` option, which "marks the file as reverted in server metadata without altering files in the client workspace". Since we are going to delete the client later, we don't care about updating the client workspace. This speeds things up if you have many files open.
2. Delete all shelved files from pending changes associated with the client.

   ```bash
   p4 changes -s shelved -c $CLIENT | cut -d' ' -f2 |
   while read CHANGE; do p4 shelve -c $CHANGE -d //...; done
   ```

   If you never use `p4 shelve` you can omit this step.
3. All pending changes associated with the client are now empty. Delete them.

   ```bash
   p4 changes -s pending -c $CLIENT | cut -d' ' -f2 | p4 -b 1 -x - change -d
   ```
4. There are now no pending changes associated with the client. Delete the client.

   ```bash
   p4 client -d $CLIENT
   ```

(This process ought to be much easier! In particular, there seems no good reason why we have to delete shelved files associated with a client before deleting the client. If you find yourself struggling with this, do contact Perforce support and suggest that it be made simpler.)

Comment: I had shelved changes on another host (after switching computers). To be able to do step 2, I had to change the host of the workspace to my current one.

Comment: The help suggests that you can use the `-f` option to force the deletion despite the mismatch. (You'll need "admin" permission though.)

Comment: The question was explicitly telling that no admin rights are available. I guess that is the case for most people who do professional work (=being paid for) with perforce.

Comment: Awesome!  Step 3 didn't work for me. Was getting "Usage: change -d [ -f ] [ -O ] changelist#
Missing/wrong number of arguments."  Slight modification worked (Mavericks): p4 changes -s pending -c $CLIENT | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -n 1 p4 change -d

Comment: @Moos: Thanks for spotting my mistake! As an alternative to `xargs`, you can use `-b 1` to batch the arguments to `p4`.

Comment: with ztag you can remove the CUT command : p4 -ztag -F'%change%'  changes -s pending -c $CLIENT | p4 -b 1 -x - change -

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I did to empty my default change set, which had a lot of files checked out for edit:

```
 p4 opened | sed 's/#.*$//g' |  xargs -iF p4 revert F
```

This will cut off the comment part from the filename produced by `p4 opened` and pipe the filename to `p4 revert`. After that I had nothing pending and `p4 changes -c my-client-name -s pending` yields nothing. If you have a huge change set this will take a while.

Comment: No need for `xargs` here (and especially no need for the `-i` option, which is unportable and deprecated even on Linux). Use `p4 -x -` instead (see `p4 help usage`). Also, to avoid the wait when you have a huge change set, use the `-k` option to `p4 revert`.

Comment: p4 opened won't necessarily show all the pending changes. you may need to use the changes command to see them.

Comment: This answer a different scenario then described in the post, you want to revert files in a default changelist ( which has no issues ) - the post is talking about states where you tried to submit -encountered an error - then Perforce will redirect all your files to a changelist even if you never requested it to.

Comment: so in your case, all you need to do in order to revert everything in your repo is `p4 revert //...`

Answer (score 5):

Wrote this script called **[p4-delete-client](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-delete-client)** for deleting a p4 client (which has changelists & other problems).
It has the following features:

- automatically deletes changelists (reverts pending & deletes shelved)
- fixes hostname (if differs from the one the client was created on)
- unlocks the client if locked
- deletes the client
- deletes associated files (can be configured not to from arguments)

> Note that the script relies on other scripts in the [repo](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u).

Answer (score 2):

try those steps :

1. 1.Right click on the changelist
2. Choose 'Change Ownership'
3. In the workspace box choose already existing workspace and click OK
4. right click on changelist  and choose delete and than ok.

Answer (score 2):

All the files need to be reverted before the change list can be deleted.

Two steps via p4v (version 2013.4):

1. Revert all files.

   `Right click the pending changelist, and then choose "Revert Files"`
2. Delete the change list.

   `Right click the changelist, and then choose "Delete Pending Changelist 'XXXXXX'"`

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me in P4V for resetting the default changelist:

1. Right click on the default changelist and choose "Edit Pending
   Changelist 'default'"
2. Click the button on the bottom right "Save as numbered changelist"
3. Right click on the new changelist and choose "Delete changelist XXX"

You can also right click on the new changelist to revert the files for whatever you need to do, which is not available as an option on the default changelist.