# Perforce: How can I delete a changelist that p4v refuses to delete?

Tags: perforce

After a while of working with perforce I was left with a lot of still open change lists.
To clean up I want to get rid of a subset of them.
So here is what makes this complicate:

- For a subset of the changes the host of the client has changed.
- Some changes contain shelved files.
- Files from the change list may be deleted or moved.

When one or more of above points are true for a change list, `p4v` (the visual client) will not allow you to delete the change list.

So what is an effective way of **deleting these change lists**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, perforce **refuses to work** on any change lists **if the host differs** in their workspace. So **step one** is to **change the host of the workspace** to the current one. This can easily be done with the visual client `p4v`. Open the properties of a workspace, choose edit and change the host.

Then you can use the command line to get rid of the pesky change list(s):

```
# to delete a changelist
CLIENT="name_of_your_client"
CHANGE="number_of_the_changelist_to_delete"
p4 -c $CLIENT shelve -c $CHANGE -d //... # Delete all shelved files from it.
p4 -c $CLIENT revert -k -c $CHANGE //... # Revert all files from changelist (only metadata).
p4 -c $CLIENT change -d $CHANGE # Finally delete the changelist.
```

After the last command the change list will be gone forever.

Comment: See also related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296080/how-to-delete-pending-changelist-in-perforce/12301548

Comment: This was actually my starting point. It failed when I only wanted to delete some of the change lists in an old client, but keep others.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the hostname can be done from the command line like this:

```bash
client_hostname="$(p4 client -o ${CLIENT} | grep "^Host" | awk '{print $2}')"
p4 client -o ${CLIENT} | sed "/^Host:/ s=${client_hostname}=${HOSTNAME}=" | p4 client -i
```

Had the same problem some time ago and wrote a script ([p4-delete-changelist](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-delete-changelist)) that overcomes all of these problems (and another one - deleting p4 fixes).

Note that the script depends on [another file](https://github.com/arnonzilca/p4u/blob/master/p4-help-functions) in the repository.