# How to delete a pending changelist in Perforce from an old workspace and offline machine (by admin access)

Tags: perforce

**Note**: I want to delete the changelist only not the client.
The answers in the following link doesn't work when the pending changelist is from an old workspace which is in an offline machine  [Perforce: How can I delete a changelist that p4v refuses to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905002/perforce-how-can-i-delete-a-changelist-that-p4v-refuses-to-delete?lq=1)

Tried the following command `p4 -u <user> -c <client> -H <host> revert -k <file(s)>`
But I'm not allowed to do as the workspace owner is different.

Comment: Please be as precise as you can about "doesn't work". What, **exactly** did you try, and what **exactly** was the behavior? As far as I know, everything in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905003/193453 still works fine.

Comment: I tried the following command after logging in as an admin : p4 -c "someclient" revert -k -c "changelist#"  //...      But I get an error that "someclient" can only be accessed by "somehost" which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the USER and CLIENT:

```
p4 describe CHANGE
```

With a 2015.1+ server at this point you can just do:

```
p4 revert -c CHANGE -C CLIENT //...
p4 change -df CHANGE
```

With an older server it's a few more steps.

First get the HOST so you can bypass the hostname check:

```
p4 client -o CLIENT
```

Now login, revert the files, and delete the change:

```
p4 login USER
p4 -u USER -c CLIENT -H HOST revert -k -c CHANGE //...
p4 change -df CHANGE
```

Comment: Thank you... My commands weren't executing successfully as the database was corrupted....sorted that out first and this worked!