# P4Python having trouble deleting client - [Error]: To delete the client, delete any pending changes first

Tags: python-2.7, perforce, p4python

While i am trying to delete a client. I am encountering error

What i am doing here is,

1) I create a temp client workspace. (Success)

2) I checkout a file for edit. (Success)

3) I checkin the file. (Success)

4) When i try to delete the client workspace. Below is the error

[Error]: "Client 'workspaceXXXX' has pending changes. To delete the client, delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client."

Below is the part of code trying to delete client

```
        try:
            self.p4.run("client", "-d", self.clientWorkspace)
            logging.info("Workspace "+self.clientWorkspace+" deleted")
        except P4Exception, e:
            logging.error(e)
            """Look for P4Exception while deleting workspace. Revert changes and try again"""
            self.revertChangeList()
```

In Exception handling i have method to revert changes in case of exception. Below is the code which will do this

```
    try:
        self.p4.run("revert", "-k","//...")[0]
        logging.info("Pending file reverted from workspace "+self.clientWorkspace)
    except P4Exception, e:
        logging.error(e)
```

Above code also gives exception [Warning]: '//... - file(s) not opened on this client.'

Comment: I found the reason. This happens when we check-out the file dont do any changes and check-in the file. Actually file doesnt get checked-in instead throws exception. But the problem is the file doesnt get reverted and has not able to delete the workspace later.

Comment: So i am thinking of checking if the file checked out is modified before check-in. Can anyone tell me how to check if file is modified after check-out.

Comment: `p4 revert -a` will revert any unmodified files.

Comment: I found the solution in the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296080/how-to-delete-a-perforce-client-with-pending-changelist/12301548